Android Studio Custom Preference breaks layout view for preferences
This has been posted over the years and it looks like it's back as an issue.
Create a new Java project with a Basic View Activity.
Add a Settings Fragment.
Check the root_preferences.xml layout to make sure it renders in Android Studio
Create a custom class, "CustomEditTextPreference" that extends "EditTextPreference":
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;

public class CustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    public CustomEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}

In root_permissions.xml, change the "EditTextPreference" to "CustomEditTextPreference".
In Android Studio 'split view' and 'design view' both show blank with a red exclamation that says "Render problem".
class android.preference.ListPreference cannot be cast to class android.preference.GenericInflater$Parent (android.preference.ListPreference and android.preference.GenericInflater$Parent are in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @3ff50027)
Listed twice.
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
No idea why it's referencing 'ListPreference' when I'm extending 'EditTextPreference'.
Is this a known issue?  The application actually runs fine; no run-time errors.
Don't know why this is occurring.  Is it a valid issue?

"Layout does not display" -- does not display where? The exception refers to com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader. So, are you referring to it not displaying in the layout editor of Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA?

Not displaying in Split view or Design view in Android Studio.  I updated the original post accordingly.

That feels like an IDE bug. You might consider creating a project that reproduces the issue, then file an issue on the official issue tracker. I do not see one that matches your symptoms.

I submitted a formal bug in the issue tracker.  It's very reproducible.

It's not an IDE bug.  It was a bug in my code.  I was using a custom ListPreference and wasn't try/catch'ing all the resource calls in the constructor so within the editor it was failing.
